# Benchmarking a squid proxy

Tags: linux, benchmarking, squid

We have a few squid proxy servers that have been running for a few years already.

I have been tasked to benchmark the service the proxy give (not the server), ideally using urls parsed from squid's log files.

I have been looking for benchmarking software, stress tests and traffic generators.

Benchmarking-wise I am quite happy with ''httperf''. It is not tailor-made for the task but it can be configured to benchmark a proxy.

When it comes to traffic generators, I have not found anything that does what I require; apparently all traffic generators emulate a number of users hitting the same site.

What I need to accomplish is the opposite: hitting multiple servers from one or few virtual users through a proxy server and get metric about that.